# How to add text to an image in React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I'm researching if it is easily possible with React Native or whether I should build a native app.

I want to edit an image  from the photo library and add a text overlay to it. Think of it like a postcard with a greeting message on it.

How would I add text to and image and make a new copy of it in react native? I'm not looking for detailed code, just for an explanation on how to get started.

**Update:**
Would it be a good alternative to just save the coordinates of the message on the picture instead of generating a new image?

Comment: Some time passed... Have you implemented a solution? I would like to do it for videos. If you have, can you post the code here?

Answer (score 19):

You can go with 2 ways. You can either render the text on an image component and save the position of that text or you can process the image and get a new image with the text.

The first option brings up the problem of that position is relative to image's size. Means that if the image renders on a different sized screen the position and size of text should also be moved accordingly. This option needs a good calculation algorithm. Also, another problem could be the rendering times. Text component will render instantly but Image component needs to load the image first. This option also needs a good way of render algorithm.

The second option is not possible without a 3rd party library or some level of native code since react-native doesn't support image processing beyond the limits of CSS. A good and maintained image processing library is [gl-react-native-v2](https://github.com/gre/gl-react-native-v2). This library helps you to process and manipulate the image as you wish and then save the result with [`captureFrame(config)`](https://github.com/gre/gl-react-v2/blob/master/docs/api/Surface.md#captureframeconfig). This option is more capable of processing file but needs you to save a new image.

Either way is good if the way you go is appropriate for your use case. The decision really depends on your case and preference.

Comment: Good answer. So you would recommend `gl-react-native` over making a snapshot with `react-native-view-shot`

Comment: @crispychicken Thank you. I can't recommend a library specifically. If another library works better for you or a better use for your case you should go with that. gl-react-native was just an example of an image processing library.

Comment: @bennygenel Any ideas about adding text to videos in react-native?

Comment: @Yossi I have no experience with it but I think the methods would be the same.

Comment: The linked version is since expired. A new version, with a beautiful online demo, is available here: https://github.com/gre/gl-react

Answer (score 5):

You could use react-native's `ImageBackground` tag since using the `Image` tag as a container would give you a *yellow box warning*.

The sample code for it with overlay is as shown below

```
<ImageBackground source={SomeImage} style=  {SomeStyle} resizeMode='SomeMode'>
   {loader}
</ImageBackground>
```

It would be efficient if you work on the same image by changing the flex property in the styles of the image or you may set the `position: absolute` to the main image container and assign `top , bottom, left, right` to the nested container.

Helpful link may be found ***[here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/9637dd4a1b78d5f6da510b1b4ad10d45d67badbf)***

Answer (score 4):

```
<View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 20}}>
    <Image
     style={{
       flex: 1,
       width:100,
       height:100,
     }}
     source={require('../imgs/star.png')}
     />
     <Text style={{position: 'absolute', fontSize: 20}}>890</Text>
 </View>
```

Answer (score 2):

> I'm researching if it is easily possible with React Native or whether I should build a native app.

This sounds very doable in react-native

> I want to edit an image from the photo library and add a text overlay to it. Think of it like a postcard with a greeting message on it.

I think I would capture **ALL** the relevant metadata as an object...

```
{
    image: {
        uri: './assets/image.jpg',
        height: 576,
        width: 1024
    },
    message: {
        fontFace: 'Calibri',
        fontSize: 16,
        text: 'Happy Holidays!'
        boundingBox: { 
            height: '30%',
            width: '30%',
            top: 0,
            left: 0
        }
    }
}
```

With the above detail (and maybe more), you'd then be able to reconstruct the design intent on any device, regardless of size (tablet vs mobile) or pixel depth. The `boundingBox` would be expressed in terms relative to the image's rendered dimensions. In the above example, the message would be contained in a text box no more than 30% of the image width, 30% of its height, and positioned in the top-left corner.

> How would I add text to an image and make a new copy of it in react native?

This eliminates the need to do any screenshotting or actual image manipulation, etc. No need to "make a new copy". Just treat them as two separate and distinct assets, then merge them at render using the metadata you captured.

Final thought: if you "need" to "upload the finished photo to a server" as you stated in another comment to another solution, you can do this serverside using any number of technologies using the metadata as your guide.

Comment: I believe your boundigBox logic has some flow on it. Although like you said, if you give relative size to the box, size of the text is always set with `fontSize`.

Comment: @bennygenel Thank you for your feedback. I'm not sure what you mean by "has some flow on it". Of course, `fontSize` would need to be relative as well, but I think the concept still conveys, don't you?

Comment: adjusting fontSize would need to calculation that involves original size of the image and the current view size of the image. you would need to calculate ratio of the change and then set the fontSize. Also it is the same for positioning. You should adjust the positioning relative to the new size. For example if the text start at `x: 100` for 500px image it should start at x: 50 for 250px.

Comment: that makes sense to me

Answer (score 2):

You can use `position: absolute` since adding children to Image is deprecated. Following code will align text in middle (vertically and horizontally) over the image:

```
<View>
    <Image
        source={yourImageUrl}
        resizeMode={'cover'}
        style={{
            width: 300,
            height: 300
        }}
    />

    <View style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, height: 300, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Your overlay text</Text>
    </View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to only show a text over the image you can wrap the image in a view and after the image insert a text element with `position: 'absolute'`. If you want a copy of the image containing the text then you can use the same approach but take a snapshot using [react-native-view-shot](https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot)

Comment: Good idea, but I think the image quality would be worse and the image dimension would decrease to phone pixel size...

Comment: What is the purpose of the app?

Comment: Display postcards on tablets with greeting message. So the image quality should be optimized for tablet size. Pictures are made with phone.

Comment: Should the user be able to save the image? If not then you can simply extract a new component with the setting I explained above

Comment: I need to upload the finished photo to a server.

Comment: I think you can set the maximum width and height of the image along with the text and then snapshot it. On the side note image processing is a little heavy task for the client side and I recommend you do it on the server

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the image component can be used as a container so you can do something like this:

```
<Image>
  <Text>{"some text"}</Text>
</Image>
```

Comment: He needs to upload the edited image to a server. Also, adding children to Image is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Below code is what I used to add text on image at particular coordinates on image.

**Xcode 8.3.2 Swift 3.1**

```
func textToImage(drawText text: NSString, inImage image: UIImage, atPoint point: CGPoint) -> UIImage {
        let textColor = UIColor.white
        let textFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Bold", size: 10)!

        let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, false, scale)

        let textFontAttributes = [
            NSFontAttributeName: textFont,
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor,
            ] as [String : Any]
        image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: image.size))

        let rect = CGRect(origin: point, size: image.size)
        text.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()


        return newImage!
    }
```

And call above method as below

```
let imageWithText = textToImage(drawText: "textOnImage", inImage:yourImage, atPoint: CGPoint(x:9,y:11))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several libraries available for that. If you want to add a text to an image you can use: [react-native-media-editor](https://github.com/Takamichi-tsutsumi/react-native-media-editor). This is quite a good option for adding text to an image but I recommend you [react-native-image-tools](https://github.com/npomfret/react-native-image-tools). It provides so much flexibility. You can add a text and position it accordingly. Apart from that, there are filters, cropping option, light adjustments and so much more.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the use case but if you simply want to put a text on an image, using `ImageBackground` is a one of the good approach.

Do it like below.

```js
<ImageBackground
  source={{ uri: hoge }}
  style={{
    height: 105,
    width: 95,
    position: 'relative', // because it's parent
    top: 7,
    left: 5
  }}
>
  <Text
    style={{
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      color: 'white',
      position: 'absolute', // child
      bottom: 0, // position where you want
      left: 0
    }}
  >
    hoge
  </Text>
</ImageBackground>
```